# SQL Server Date casting and format issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to convert my existing sql dates in a table which is stored in `yyyy-mm-dd` format using following command to `dd-mm-yyyy`. While doing so I can successfully convert it to `nvarchar` data type but when convert it as date I receive still same old format of `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Here is query

```
Select 
    Convert(date, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), a.LogDateTime, 103), 103) AS LDate  
from sec.[Log] AS a
```

I did also try to convert from `nvarchar` to date using following script but result remain same.

```
SELECT convert(date, '23/10/2016', 103)
```

Can any one tell what exactly the problem is? As I want my date to get convert to british format from us format without changing its datatype.

Answer (score 2):

Dates are not stored in ANY textual format. a DATETIME value is stored in an internal format, taking 8 bytes of disk storage. It is **NOT** stored in text form.

FYI, yyyy-mm-dd is not a US format. It is just a universally accepted, unambiguous display format that the SQL Server team decided to use to display date values within SQL Server Management Studio.

If you have to show it in a particular form, you must do so in the display layer, such as your Visual Studio created desktop application.  Unfortunately, there is no setting to control the default format in SSMS, so you will just have to CONVERT it with with the right format (103) if you intend to view it in SSMS.

```
declare @d datetime
set @d = '20120506'
select CONVERT(char(10), @d, 103) -- or column instead of variable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  CONVERT (VARCHAR(15), logdatetime, 105)
FROM    sec.[log]
```